# Android - What is outputX/outputY and aspectX/aspectY when crop an image from gallery or camera?

Tags: android, crop, android-camera-intent

I read a lot of posts about cropping an image from gallery or camera, and I know outputX/outputY refers to the size of the output/cropped image. However, nobody ever explained what does aspectX/aspectY do? And what is the unit of outputX/outputY? Is it `dp`?

Sample code: [Modify Android crop intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880253/modify-android-crop-intent)

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are [many image cropping libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) available. Please use one.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know. I'm not using this, but I just wondering, because tons of examples like this floating around on the internet. Thanks for point it out though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aspectX and aspectY are the ratio of width and height of the result image, if you need to scale it. `width / height = aspectX / aspectY`

And I don't think the unit of outputX and outputY are `dp`. I think its just pixel.

Answer (score 6):

`aspectX` and `aspectY` are just a proportion, so if you want an 16:9 image putting `aspectX = 16` and `aspectY = 9` you get the desired ratio.

Good Luck!

Comment: so... is it going to stretch the image?

Comment: You will have a stretched image if aspectX/aspectY != outputX/outpuxY

for example: 
aspectX = 100
aspectY= 100
outputX = 16
outputY = 9
you will have an image of 16:9 condensed in square image of 100x100

Comment: What if you want the cropper tool to not have a fixed ratio? I mean i want to allow users to crop images to a rectangle or a square as they want.

Comment: You need to quit aspect and output values, just removing aspect values your users can crop images as they want, and removing output values you will get the image with the user's desired size.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try

Comment: I tried removing outputx and outputy It is showing "Saving Picture" endlessly.